# omp_init_lock(omp_lock_t*) - What does this function do EXACTLY?

Tags: c++, linux, openmp

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <omp.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define NUM_THREADS SIZE

using namespace std;

main() {

omp_lock_t lock;
//omp_init_lock(&lock);

srand(time(NULL));  

int arr[SIZE], max = -1;

omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = rand()%100;

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    omp_set_lock(&lock);
        if(arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    omp_unset_lock(&lock);
}

cout << "Max: " << max << endl;
```

}

This is the code, I wrote to find the max element in an array using openMP lock feature. Whenever I skipped that function `omp_init_lock`, my code would not execute. It would still compile successfully but all my threads would stop after they entered the for loop **whenever the SIZE of the array was a small number (like 10 or 20)**. Other times it would run without problems (when the size of the array was a large number like 100).

But `omp_init_lock()` solves all problems. How? I searched but could not find much about it. Only thing mentioned was that it initializes the lock to an unlocked state. Why is the code running when size of the array is 100 even though I don't initialize the lock?

So what exactly is `omp_init_lock()` doing in detail?

Answer (score 6):

An OpenMP lock can be in one of three possible states: *unintialized*, *unlocked*, or *locked* (Section 3.3 of the [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf)). When declared, but not initialised via a call to `omp_init_lock()`, a lock is in *unitialized* state. Calling `omp_init_lock()` transitions the lock into *unlocked* state. From then on, the lock can be first *locked* using `omp_set_lock()` and then *unlocked* using `omp_unset_lock()`.

Calling `omp_set_lock()` on a lock that is in *uninitialized* state is erroneous (Section 3.3.4). Calling `omp_unset_lock()` on a lock that is not in *locked* state, which includes *uninitialized*, is also erroneous (Section 3.3.5).

That your program works under *specific conditions* without properly initialising the lock is an **unspecified behaviour**.

Comment: Thanks. :) It should throw a warning or error at least to let people know that the state of the lock is uninitialized. Oh, well.

Comment: The lock operation is supposed to be as fast as possible, therefore checking the lock variable each and every time is simply not practical. There are correctness checking tools that detect such problems in your code, such as Thread Analyzer (part of Oracle Solaris Studio, former Sun Studio).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `omp_init_lock` function is initializing the lock variable for setting/unsetting. This would include allocating any required memory used for the lock and setting the initial state to 'unlocked'. You should expect unpredictable results without proper initialization.

> OMP_INIT_LOCK     Initializes a lock associated with the lock variable

Source: [LLNL OpenMP Tutorials](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#OMP_SET_LOCK)